# Disable a button on a panel which is NOT a form

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

I have a panel which is not a form, yet it's used like a form.  I need to disable the "addButton" button when a text field is invalid.  The disabling in the text Field's validator function works, but visually the button still looks enabled.
How can I tell a button to be visually disabled via the validator method on my text field?

Here is the code:

```
      items: [
    {
      xtype: 'textfield',
      validator: function(value) {
        var reg = /^\d+(,\d+)*$/;
        var addButton =  this.ownerCt.down('[itemId=addButton]');
        if (reg.test(value)===false) {
          addButton.disabled=true;
          addButton.allowDepress=false;
          return "Enter whole numbers separated by comma";

        }
        addButton.disabled=false;
        addButton.allowDepress=false;
        return true;

      },
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is working sample http://jsfiddle.net/H76fQ/2/

```
var button = Ext.create('Ext.button.Button',{
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    text: 'Ok',
    disabled: true
});

Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Text',{
    allowBlank: false,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    listeners:{
        afterrender: function(){
            this.validate();
        },
        validitychange: function(me, isValid){
            button.setDisabled(!isValid);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, I needed to call that setDisabled function rather than the property directly.  Now it works like a charm - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To disable the FormPanel’s submit button,You can set the FormPanel’s monitorValid to true and the submit button’s formBind to true.

```js
items: [{
  xtype: 'ux.form',
  monitorValid: true, // Must be added 
  layout: {
  type: 'hbox',
  align: 'start',
  pack: 'stretch'
  },
  items: [{
    name:"testing",
    xtype:'textfield',
    fieldLabel:'Test',
    allowBlank:false,   // This is the property which will check the validation
    },
    {
    xtype: 'ux.button',
    text: 'Submit',
    width: 120,
    formBind: true
  }]
}]
```